# JSF2 Disabling focus for button in composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I want to disable focus for button in composite component.
I have a component that looks like this:
[image]

When I'm pressing the "Tab" key, first the inputText component is focused, then the commandButton component is focused. 
What I want is to have focused only the inputText.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would try tabindex="-1", dont have time to try it myself now tho :(

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you please reply with an answer so that I can accept your solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <h:commandButton ... tabindex="-1">
```

The
 attribute tabindex defines in which order the component will be selected in the tab cycle. Documentation for [h:commandButton](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) states for attribute tabindex:

> Position of this element in the tabbing order for the current
>   document. This value must be an integer between 0 and 32767

But i guess above can be ignored, as on the other hand [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) states (for html5):

> **If the value is a negative integer**
>
> The user agent must set the
>   element's tabindex focus flag, but should not allow the element to be
>   reached using sequential focus navigation